# php, why is the session id is the same from two browsers?

Tags: php, session

I have a site, when I log in with the same user with two browsers, the session_id() tells me the same value. Isnt it wrong? How to distinguish the two users?

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, unless you are [passing session IDs via the URL](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) and have opened the same session-id-containing URL in both browsers.

Comment: I hope you mean two different browsers and not two windows of the same browser.

Comment: note: if you copied the session id, check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Prevention

Comment: The chances of this occuring in a properly configured setup are so small they're almost 0... So a misconfiguration is most likely. Are you letting vanilla php sessions generate the session-id, or is your script doing something on it's own?

Comment: Without any code there's little chance of giving a meaningful answer, other than the one @lanzz gave, and assuming "two different browsers" really means two different browser programs or the same program running on two different computers and not two windows of the same browser on the same computer.

Comment: yea different browsers, different tabs, im not stupid

Comment: why no code , start all over and improve question !

Comment: due to the fact that this is a serious bug in google chrome, we should  not downvote this anymore. more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954917/chrome-is-creating-duplicate-sessions-with-the-same-id

Comment: @JohnSmith He John, Google pays a lot of money for Chrome bugs, so you  might check the chrome bugreport system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE/EDIT: Google Chrome seems to have a SERIOUS issue with exactly what you wrote, see this [Chrome is creating duplicate sessions with the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954917/chrome-is-creating-duplicate-sessions-with-the-same-id) and http://code.google.com/p/webug/issues/detail?id=12 for more info.

My older answer:

If you are REALLY using two different browsers, then you are probably

1. using are NON-server-based session script OR
2. you are providing the session via something (url parameter ?) OR
3. you are using a very strange session system (yes, i have seen that) which tracks users by their IPs.

Typical PHP sessions are created as files on the server filesystem,
    so a "new browser" does not know about this session and the browser has no info about you that it could send to the server.

If you want a REAL answer, show some code, dude.