# Button Click is fired automatically on Page Reload

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, firefox, prefetch

I am facing a very strange problem. I have the following code in my `button click event` which gets and inserts values into the `database`.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

            If txtInvoiceNumber.Text.Trim = "" Or txtTransactionAmount.Text.Trim = "" Then
                'Label7.Visible = True
            Else
                If txtFirstName.Text.Trim <> "" Then
                    Utilities.InsertVirtualTransactions(txtCardNumber.Text.Trim, txtTransactionAmount.Text.Trim, txtInvoiceNumber.Text.Trim, txtTerminalID.Text, ddlProduct.SelectedValue())
                    Label1.Visible = True
                    'Label7.Visible = False
                    dsCards = Utilities.GetVirtualResultNew(txtCardNumber.Text.Trim, txtTerminalID.Text, txtTransactionAmount.Text.Trim)
                    grdTransactionResult.DataSource = dsCards
                    grdTransactionResult.DataBind()
                    DisableFields()
                    Label1.Visible = True
                    btnSearch.Visible = False
                    RemoveFields()
                    btnSubmit.Enabled = False
                Else
                    Response.Write("<script> alert('Please select Branch from'); </script>")

                End If
            End If

        End Sub
```

This works absolutely fine BUT if user selects `Chrome's` `Duplicate` right-click menu option OR `Firefox's` `Reload Tab` option to open the same page in another tab, this `btnSubmit_Click`
event is fired again and posts `duplicate` transactions. Why is it happening? How can the browser fire the button click event automatically?

Here is my `Page Load` event if it has something to do with this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                If Session("Login") = "Success" Then
                    loadvirtualCard()
                    DisableFields()
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Can you look for delegates in your designer auto-generated code which might be calling your btnSubmit_Click

Comment: But if thats the case, why IE works fine? Why varying behaviour browser to browser?

Comment: What might be happening is, when you try to open in a new tab, it re-executes the last transaction

Comment: Yes it does. How can I prevent this? Can you think of any solution?

Comment: You can check a similar issue addressed in another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954917/chrome-is-creating-duplicate-sessions-with-the-same-id